# Convert a Rails2 namespace route to rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this code in Rails2:

```
map.namespace(:admin, :path_prefix => 'refinery') do |admin|

  admin.load_gallery "/load_gallery", :controller => "pages", 
                                  :action => "load_gallery"
end
```

..and want to convert it to rails3 route. Is there any possibility that someone can demonstrate how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might look like

```
scope 'refinery', :as => :admin do
  match 'load_gallery'=> 'pages#load_gallery'
end
```

Comment: Ok, thanks it gave me the insight! However, the controller belonged to a module and I had to also add :module => :admin